# Is there a way in XAML to select all text in textbox when double clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to highlight all text in textbox purely through XAML, or does it have to be done in the Xaml.cs

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do it in xaml alone, but you don't have to do it in the code-behind specifically. You can write a behavior to accomplish it. Then you can apply that behavior using xaml only. Here is an example that should get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgartner/archive/2009/11/11/wpf-attached-behavior-example-watermark-text.aspx

Comment: I could show you exact example for problem with behaviour as suggested by Henrik. You asked that to highligh all text in textbox when doble clicked on textbox. But it is indeed acting like that by defualt in WPF.

Comment: Thanks for the replys, I am taking a look at the example Henrik posted.

Comment: Farhad: when I double click the text it is only highlighting one word, I thought it should highlight all by default.  Thanks Again

Comment: That sounds like expected behavior, I think 3 clicks invokes SelectAll()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what you are going to do:

First, add `DoubleClickBehavior.cs` class to your Project.

```
class DoubleClickBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick += AssociatedObjectMouseDoubleClick;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick -= AssociatedObjectMouseDoubleClick;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private void AssociatedObjectMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
        }
    }
```

Then in `.xaml`, add this behavior to your TextBox:

```
<TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:DoubleClickBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

You need to add two namepsaces to your `.xaml` to use your behavior. (The name of my project was `WpfApplication1`, so you will probably need to change that):

```
 xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

That's it. Also you need `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` to use the `Behavior` class.

You can download it from the [Nuget Package Manager](http://nuget.org/packages/Blend.Interctivity.WPF.v4.0/1.0.3).

Answer (score 7):

With a TextBox, you can add the `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` event.

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="MyTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="TextBoxSelectAll"/>
```

Then you set the [TextBox.SelectedText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx) of the `TextBox` to the text in the `TextBox`.

```
private void TextBoxSelectAll(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    // Set the event as handled
    e.Handled = true;
    // Select the Text
    (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: As he said, he wants to achieve taht through xaml. But, anyway it is also helpful.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Your `Behaviour` does the same thing, in my XAML, the selecting of the text is directly attached to the action of double-clicking. In your XAML, you add the `Behaviour` to attach the event. Same thing, mine seems simpler.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev How so? Is the selection of text not considered part of the GUI (View) and not part of `Model` or the `ViewModel`?

Comment: Am I wrong? I am somehow newbie in MVVM. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev I don't believe there is any MVVM, manipulation of the TextBox is part of the UI, and not manipulation of data since there is no change in data, different than if we manipulate data (i.e. changing `TextBox.Text` to something else).

Comment: haa.Of course, you are right. Sorry, I am really tired, because i have not slept about 2days. Yes, There is not anything about MVVM.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the input. I agree with you, however personally I think its nice to show a simple solution (for WPF newbies), then advance towards using `Behaviours`. :)