# How to get listview datatemplate item doubleclicked WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

How can I bind to a datatemplate which is show in a listview and is being doubleclicked?

I want smthing like this:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"></CheckBox>
```

I already have everything done, but don't know how to bind a command to a datatemplate in listview or to a Grid in that datatemplate.

Datatempalte is like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ServerViewItemTemplate" DataType="ViewModel:ServerViewModel">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="ServerId:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ServerId}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Login:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Password:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Password}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Type:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Type}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="IpAddress:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding IpAddress}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Text="Include:"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"></CheckBox>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

So if it is double-clicked it should call the ICommand, the same as in the CheckBox AddItemCommand.

Comment: if you wanna show anything with a datatemplate, just bind the object to a contentpresenter Content property.

Comment: I have a listview which contains datatemplates, and I wanna handle a double click on the datatemplate.

Comment: pls update your question and give some more information

Comment: Just updated. Hope it will help=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a Behavior to handle the double click event. Depending on what you want to do when you double click, you may need to add an `ICommand` Dependency Property to the Behavior so you can bind to a command on your viewmodel.

Here's a similar post: [Is there a way in XAML to select all text in textbox when double clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041556/is-there-a-way-in-xaml-to-select-all-text-in-textbox-when-double-clicked/16042596#comment22891353_16042596)

In that example, the user is selecting text in a TextBox when double clicked.

MORE:

Your XAML will look something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ServerViewItemTemplate" DataType="ViewModel:ServerViewModel">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">

        <Grid>
            <e.Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:DoubleClickBehavior Command="{Binding Path=AddItemCommand}"/>
            </e.Interaction.Behaviors>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
... ...
```

Comment: I have just updated my question, hope it will help you to help me=)

Comment: You should really add more code. Add your `DataTemplate` with a better explanation of what you'd like to happen. I've already given you an example of how to handle the double click. I'll need more info if what I've given you isn't enough to answer your question.

Comment: @user1669713 OK...my original post still stands. Follow the highest voted answer on that page and you'll accomplish part of what you want. The other part (using the double click to execute a command) is explained in my original post (you need to make a Dependency Property in the Behavior). The Behavior could go on either the `Grid` inside the `DataTemplate`, making the `Grid` the `AssociatedObject` in the Behavior.

Comment: But what about MVVM? Won't it violate the pattern?

Comment: What about it? You're still adhering to it just fine. There's still a separation of concerns. There is no coupling between the double click behavior and the view.

Comment: The problem is to create Behavior class, I can't use it by using System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior; VS11 says that doesn't know it.

Comment: You don't need that assembly. You only need "namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity" which you can get from the Blend SDK or from the NuGet package manager. It says all of this in the post I linked to.

Comment: I've got with the NuGet Interactivity, but haven't know about namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity Thank you very much! You have greate patience=) You are a great man!